# Dicionários recebendo lista com valores

Tags: python, python-3.x

Galera meu código esta tendo uns pequenos problemas, ele recebe "instituiçoes"(nomes que o usuario quiser no input) dentro de um dicionario esse input ta passando pro dicionario como uma lista, e depois uso a lista pra fazer uma "doação" até ai ta tranquilo o problema acontece quando esta em um laço de repetição fazendo esse processo mais de uma vez na parte da "instituição" funciona normalmente sem sobrescrever o anterior porem quando e na doação o ultimo valor adicionado e subsistido pelo atual ex: foi doado 1000 e na segunda doação foi doado mais 200 deveria guarda o valor 1200, porem o valor 1000 some e fica somente o ultimo valor o 200, aqui esta o código, se poderem ajuda o mais rápido possível.

```
instituicoes = []
def doação():
    while True:
       instituicao_add = input("0 para deixar de adicionar\ndigite alguma instituicao\n:") #ex: 'stack overflow pt'
       if(instituicao_add == '0'):
           break
       instituicoes.append({'nome': instituicao_add})
    while True:
       for i, xc in enumerate(instituicoes):
            print(i,"-",xc)
       x = int(input("\nQual instituição deseja escolher?")) # ex: 0

    while x >= len(instituicoes) or x < 0: # Verificar se index existe na nossa lista de instituicoes
        x = int(input("\nQual instituição deseja escolher?")) # ex: 0

        dinheiro = int(input("\nQuanto deseja doar?\n"))

        instituicoes[x]['doação'] = dinheiro # ex: 1000
        print("Obrigado por ajudar esta instituição")
        print(instituicoes[x]) # output: {'nome':'stack overflow pt', 'doação': 1000}

    #para imprimir só o valor doado
        print(instituicoes[x]['doação'])
doação()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consigo testar esse código agora. Mas tente  cada vez que adiciona uma instituição pode definir também a doação a 0

nesta linha pode ficar:

```
...
instituicoes.append({'nome': instituicao_add, 'doação': 0})
...
```

despois mais tarde é só incrementar a doação na instituição que desejar doar:

```
...
instituicoes[x]['doação'] += dinheiro
...
```

Estruturei um pouco melhor o seu código com base naquilo que me pareceu que queria:

```
instituicoes = []
def doação():
    while True:
       instituicao_add = input("0 para deixar de adicionar\ndigite alguma instituicao\n:")
       if(instituicao_add == '0'):
           break
       instituicoes.append({'nome': instituicao_add, 'doação': 0})

    for i, v in enumerate(instituicoes):
       print(i, '-', instituicoes[i])

    for i in instituicoes: #não sei bem se é isto que quer, pelo o código que mostrou parece que quer que o numero de doações a fazer sejam iguais ao numero de instituiçoes que temos

       x = int(input("\nQual instituição deseja escolher?"))
       while x >= len(instituicoes) or x < 0: 
           x = int(input("\nNão existe na lista. Qual instituição deseja escolher?"))

       dinheiro = int(input("\nQuanto deseja doar a " +instituicoes[x]['nome']+ "?\n"))
       instituicoes[x]['doação'] += dinheiro
       print("Obrigado por ajudar esta instituição: ", instituicoes[x]['nome'])
       print(instituicoes[x])

    print(instituicoes)

doação()
```

Comment: Certo o código e basicamente aquele que vc tinha corrigido antes com pequenas mudanças mas são besteiras, vou testa e lhe passo o feedback.

Comment: Exatamente isso cara, vlw você é o cara nota 10.

Comment: Obrigado. Ainda  bem que ajudei @Alysson

Comment: só a nível de curiosidade teria como somar o resultado final se eu tivesse vamos supor 4 ou mais instituições  no caso tudo arrecadado ?

Comment: O total de todas as doaçoẽs? No final até pode fazer em duas linhas: `doacoes = [i['doação'] for i in instituicoes]` e na linha abaixo pode `total = sum(doacoes)` . Esta maneira chama-se list compreension. Você poderia atingir o mesmo só com ciclo for